# curl utf-8 special character after download

Tags: curl, utf-8

When I use curl with [this link](http://www.radiopilatus.ch/livecenter?action=webradio) to find the current artist and title:

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -t utf-8 \
    -s http://www.radiopilatus.ch/livecenter?action=webradio \
   | grep "Jetzt Läuft" -A3 | tail -n 1
```

The output is both the artist and title - e.g.:

STEFANIE HEINZMANN
DIGGIN' IN THE DIRT

it should just be the title - e.g.:

```
DIGGIN' IN THE DIRT
```

How can the title be returned (without the artist)?

### Edit:

yes this is correct, The `<br>` is not my problem.
I have not see here is automatic changed from :

[image]

-
How can change to correct output?

Comment: I'm not seeing the special character; which one is it?

Comment: "*I have not see here is automatic changed from*" - what does that mean?

Comment: show on the pic from Edit:

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the call/pipe to `grep` finds the line containing both the artist and title, with a break tag (i.e. `<br>`) between the two.

[image]

In order to only show the title, you may need to use a string function (e.g. [sed](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sed/)) to remove the contents before the break tag.

`curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -t utf-8 -s http://www.radiopilatus.ch/livecenter?action=webradio | grep "Jetzt Läuft" -A3 | tail -n 1 |sed -e 's/.*<br>//'`

You can see this in action on [Teh (PHP) Playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/Uj8x01qu2OIduSF0).